# Having trouble publishing from map documents

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am attempting to create an operational layer for the Flex viewer. I am having difficulty getting my mxd to publish correctly (not visible when on server). Here is the error message I get after I create a layer package and try to publish using publish tool in ArcMap 10.

> Possible cause of connection failure: the soc cannot resolve the path
>   to the data, or the soc account has not been granted read permissions
>   of the data. In the case of ArcSDE, direct connect may not be
>   configured properly, or the soc account may not have permission to
>   access the database.

Any one know what I should do?

Comment: @Hairy - I'm seeing the error message, it's in a quote. And what do you mean by "almost added an answer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that when you created the MXD, you may not have checked store relative path, which is situated on the file manu in ArcMap.  Open your mxd in ArcMap, check that it is/isn't set and republish it.

If it is set to storing the relative path, then the only real alternative to the error is that the MXD, or data, is situated in an area in which the SOC account has no permissions.  So if the first one doesn't work, then go back and ensure that the folder the mxd is in, and all data, is shared by the SOC/SOM accounts.

When you add data to a map, the pathname to the data is stored in the map. When you 
open your map, ArcMap locates the data it needs using these stored pathnames. If you 
plan to distribute your maps to others or if the location of your data has changed, you 
may need to change how your map references data so that when you save the map, others 
will not need to repair layers.

[Referencing data in the map](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.1/index.cfm?TopicName=Referencing%20data%20in%20the%20map)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** 
I ran into this same problem. The data was stored in SDE, connecting with an SDE user account, not the same SOC account. The problem is that SOC does not have access to the SDE connection file (.sde). This was resolved when I copied the sde connection to a folder accessible by the SOC user.

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap will always give you a warning when you are accessing data via a UNC share. I have not found a way to turn off this error.

In windows explorer, go to the folder that contains your data, right click and select properties and the security tab. The ArcSOC account, or a user group that the ArcSOC account is a member of, must have read access to this folder. Otherwise when you publish, the server does not have access to read the data.

Comment: this is simply false

Answer (score 1):

I have randomly received the same error when publishing a map service from ArcMap.  This has worked for me when I get that error...
1. In your ArcMap Document Save Map Service Definition.
2. Close ArcMap
3. Open ArcCatalog
4. Go to the Map Service Definition you saved from your ArcMap document
5. Right Click Map Service Definition file
6. Publish to ArcGIS Server...

You are really doing the same thing, just in a different way.  Not sure why it works one way and not the other, but sometimes it doesn't.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, ArcGIS server (the ArcSOC account) cannot get to the data.

You should check that the data is at a location that ArcSOC can access. The best way to find out any issues, is to use the [Map Service Publishing toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sq00000018000000.htm) to analyze your map.

It will often point out any issues that you could possibly face.

I would suggest that you have a look at this page **[Preparing resources for publishing as services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000005v000000)**
 You need to make sure that the ArcSOC account has read rights on the folder that contains the data.  Having UNC path is not a major problem. It is just not as fast as a local path, since Networking comes into play.

Just make sure that ArcSOC account has read permissions and it should work out fine.

Comment: The Map Service tool will not check to see if you are storing relative paths, so will not pick up on this potential problem.

Comment: Thanks guys,Paths were set but still the same results I do get a warning that the layers data source is referenced by a unc path. Is there a way to fix this or to give thesoc access to the folder that contains the data?

Comment: Have you checked that you are storing the relative path as mentioned below?

Comment: @Hairy It's irrelevant if you are using Absolute paths or relative paths. ArcGIS server can pick up the data in either way. The problem the user is facing is that ArcSOC just can't get through to the Data

Comment: @jay I have expanded my answer to reflect your comment

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe thats just incorrect; if you have pathnames embedded in the Mxd, you have to ensure the MXD is changed to make sure it follows relative paths, otherwise it can lose the link at the server end.  I know this is true, as I have been caught out by it a few times; please don't simply dismiss it.

Comment: Maybe the soc account doesn't have read permissions to the UNC path?  Hold the shift key down and right click on Arcmap startup and choose "runas a different user" and enter credentials for the soc account.  Then see what happens when you open the mxd being used by the mapservice.

Comment: @Hairy [citation needed]

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe - Provided...

Comment: Problem solved thanks for your help guys. problem was access to the folder from the soc.